# Capturing X lines in fluentd

Tags: regex, fluentd

I'm trying to make `fluentd` listen on a tcp socket, which will receive lines of ascii input, and capture groups of 100 lines into each event.

I have seen that there is a tcp input which supports a format `multiline`. As in this example:

```
format multiline
format_firstline /^Started/
format1 /Started (?<method>[^ ]+) "(?<path>[^"]+)" for (?<host>[^ ]+) at (?<time>[^ ]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+)\n/
format2 /Processing by (?<controller>[^\u0023]+)\u0023(?<controller_method>[^ ]+) as (?<format>[^ ]+?)\n/
```

Unfortunately in the case of my data, every line has the same format, so I can't determine based on the line's format where one event should start and where it ends. Instead I want it to just always take X (in my case 100) lines together into one event, and then start the next event.

I've been trying fancy multi-line regular expressions like this one, but I suspect `fluentd` always just matches them line by line, so it will never match a multi line regex:

```
format /^(?<data>(?:[^ ]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+\r){100})$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcp` input doesn't support multiline for now.
Your case, capture X lines into one event, is very rare so writing your parser is better than combination complex configurations.

http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/plugin-development#parser-plugins